How to get file from Get Metadata activity in ADF when file name is unknown
I have a file in the ODS layer of the gen2 datalake that is transformed to parquet from source. This name will change each time it is loaded into the ODS layer. I want to be able to grab that .snappy.parquet file in ADF whatever the file name is on that occasion. I currently have dataset that looks like this:

I thought setting my Get Metadata activity like this would grab the parquet file regardless of the file name:

But this doesn't work. It says it cannot find the file.
There will always only be one file in the folder that ends .snappy.parquet - is there a way to grab this file without knowing the file name? The field list must be set to "size" as this is what I need for comparison in the next step on the pipeline.

You are using wildcard filepath in the Get meta data activity filepath. Currently, it's not supported in Get meta data activity.
To achieve your requirement, follow the below approach.
First delete the file path parameter in the dataset and keep only the folder path parameter. Give your folder path and use Child items property in the Get meta data activity.

This will give all the files list in your folder like below.

As you only have one .snappy.parquet file, filter that file using Filter activity like below.
Items : @activity('Get Metadata1').output.childItems
Condition : @endswith(item().name, '.snappy.parquet')


It will give the desired file name in the output.

Now, use another Get meta data activity with folder path and file name dataset parameters and give the required property size.
Give the above filter output file name for the filename parameter.
@activity('Filter1').output.value[0].name


It will give the desired result like below.

